# Can I retrieve the identity of what is "highlighted" with the keyboard in the browser?

Tags: html, xml, browser, navigation, keyboard

My pic: http://boards.420chan.org/prog/src/1428705769365.jpg

I'm talking about how you can use tab and arrow keys and enter to navigate the net. How can I retrieve the identity of the selected link or what-have-you like in my pic? Not just the link itself but all the associated xml too.

The goal here is getting a separate client-side program to retrieve the physical(?) location of the link on the screen and move the cursor to it, replacing the arrow in my pic. I ultimately want to build a program that can read certain xml tags in keyboard-selected links which interact with a set of client-side variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery you can can use

```
$('a').on('focus', function() { console.log(this, 'focus'); });
```

to detect focus on the link (the one usually triggered by tab.

Alternatively

```
$('a').on('mouseover', function() { console.log(this, 'hovered'); });
```

to detect when user is hovering with mouse over the element.